# Pass ID corresponding to user selection of friendly name on form to SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a form with several comboboxes, datepickers and text entry fields.  The form is using php for some processing and the values that are provided for selection are retrieved from SQL Server.

For the comboboxes I am selecting the primary key value along with the friendly name, and displaying the friendly name in the combobox.

```
    <select name="locationSelect"><option> Choose Location </option>
<?php

$sql = "SELECT ID, locationName FROM dbo.tblLocation ORDER BY locationName";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query");
while ($data=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo '<option value="'.$data['locationName'].'">';
    echo $data['locationName']; 
    echo "</option>";
}

?>
```

The selected values are passed to an action page using POST.  What I want to do is take the ID value corresponding to the locationName and use that in my insert statement on the action page.

I have tried setting a variable = the POST value for locationName and using that as a filter to select the ID from the database and assigning that value to another variable, but I am not getting any results when echoing the array or the page fails to load completely:

```
 $locationpost = $_POST['locationSelect'];
 $location = $sql = SELECT ID FROM dbo.tblLocation where locationName = '$locationpost';
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query");
 echo $location
```

I'm completely lost at this point and my Google-fu is failing me in returning anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that on this line:

```
echo '<option value="'.$data['locationName'].'">';
```

You just want to set the option value to the `ID` instead of the `locationName`.

That way you don't need to do a sql query on the next page to get the `ID` based on the `locationName`.

Comment: Incredible that it was so easy.  Thank you so much.